# Abelian group whose quotient is $p$-divisible

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group of finite torsion-free rank which has no $p$-divisible subgroup. The group $G$ has a free subgroup $F$ of finite rank and the quotient $G/F$ is $p$-divisible. Can be proved that the $p$-component of $G$ is finite?

Comment: Do you have an example of such a group?

Comment: These groups are trated in the section 3 of this [article](http://math.ubbcluj.ro/~bodo/preprints/abwfinal1.pdf), even though there is no example..however it seems they do exist.

Comment: If I could prove, that the $p$-component of $G$ is countable, I would know what to do then.